# How to specify Start Method for Powershell

Tags: function, powershell, startup

I have writen a Powershell script and at console, i normally specify start function to start script execution. But I want the script should itself specify start function e.g, `My-Function` itself to start execution when I run the script. i.e just by typing the script name and enter`..> myscript.ps1`, it should start execution from `My-Function`. How I specify the start-up function in script?

Comment: just remove the function.

Comment: @ Gerald: for some reason, i dont want to remove, any solution please?

Comment: well, alternatively you can just invoke it right after the definition. makes it pretty pointless though.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you can either move that code out of the function (which I actually wouldn't recommend usually) or just invoke the function immediately:

```
function MyFunc {
    # stuff
}

MyFunc
```

PowerShell doesn't have a concept of an entry point if that's what you're thinking about.

A more generic solution where you might want to specify a function to call as a parameter in the script but have a default, you can make the script take the function name as a parameter that has a default value.

Very top of the script:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    $FunctionName = 'Func1'
)

function Func1 {
    # does stuff
}

function Func2 {
    # does other stuff
}

Invoke-Expression -Command $FunctionName
```

I don't really like this. And it's dangerous (any PowerShell code passed in as a function name would be executed).